# Custom dates tick marks on ggplot

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I would like to plot the following data:

```
set.seed(5)
my_df <- data.frame(date = sample(seq(as.Date("2019-07-03"), as.Date("2019-07-30"), by = 1), 10), val_1 = 1:10, val_2 = 11:20) 

my_df<- gather(my_df, "type", "value", -date)
ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x= date, y=value, colour = type)) + geom_line()
```

The above only shows some dates as tick marks, not all 10. How can I show all date as tick marks. I tried `scale_x_discrete(labels = unique(my_df$date))`, but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried `scale_x_date`?

Comment: Your dates are not uniformly spaced, so when I add `scale_x_date(breaks = unique(my_df$date))` many of them overlap. Do you intend to just increase the frequency of ticks/labels?

Comment: @r2evans, Thank you! I need dates evenly spaced. I should have plotted simple sequence (on x axis) and put labels of dates on top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat dates as factor

```
ggplot(data = my_df,
  aes(x = as.factor(date), y = value, colour = type, group = type)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: Plot]

You can also use scale_x_date that @r2evans mentioned:

```
ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x= date, y=value, colour = type)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = unique(my_df$date), minor_breaks = NULL) +
#Added for readability
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1))
```

[image: Plot2]

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to *throw away* information (the fact that they are discrete dates) like this. Additionally, the data is not uniformly spaced, so doing this skews/stretches the data.

Comment: How can I add vertical line at date "2019-07-19".  I tried `geom_vline(xintercept=as.Date("2019-07-19") , linetype="dashed", color = "blue")`, but it did not work.

Comment: @r2evans
Good point. I've made some more research and find scale_x_date you pointed in the comment above.

Comment: Thank you! I tried date as factor and it did not work. Adding `group = type` fixed the problem. Why do we need `group = type` when we already have `colour = type`. There is already grouping based on color.